# Sorting list of strings according to different criteria

Tags: java, sorting

I want to sort my list of strings in reversed order but all empty string should be at the beginning of list.
I wrote my comparator for empty strings:

```
public static Comparator<String> emptyValuesFirst() {
    return new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            if (o1.length() == 0 && o2.length() == 0) {
                return 0;
            } else if (o1.length() == 0 && o2.length() > 0) {
                return 1;
            } else if (o1.length() > 0 && o2.length() == 0) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

but then when I try to use it here:

```
            Assertions.assertThat(valuesInSortedColumn)
                    .isSortedAccordingTo(Comparator.reverseOrder().thenComparing(Comparators.emptyValuesFirst()));
```

I receive an error:

> Cannot resolve method 'thenComparing(Comparator)'

Comment: Try `Comparator<String> c = emptyValuesFirst().thenComparing(Comparator.reverseOrder());` Your method is not a method of `Comparators`. If the ordering is wrong then we can try something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. in your `if` statements first `if` checks for both strings have length of 0, so when code reach first `else if` statement there is no way that o1 has length of 0 and o2 has length of 0, and as string length cannot be below zero you can improve your 1st `else if` statement to `else if (o1.length() == 0)` and your 2nd `else if` statement to `else if (o2.length() == 0)`
2. Use `Comparator.<String>reverseOrder()` instead of `Comparator.reverseOrder()` looks like java cannot guess the generic type
3. You want to sort "empty strings first, and after this reverse order" so you have to use this sorting: **all empty strings are less than non empty string, all non empty strings reverse-compared** so:

```java
    public static Comparator<String> emptyValuesFirst() {
        return new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                if (o1.length() == 0 && o2.length() == 0) {
                    //if both strings empty they are same
                    return 0;
                } else if (o1.length() == 0) {
                    //if o1 is empty then it less than o2
                    return -1;
                } else if (o2.length() == 0) {
                    //if o2 is empty then o1 is greater then 02
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    //string are equals comparing by *is empty*
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

**Usage:**

```java
        List<String> valuesInSortedColumn = new ArrayList<>();
        valuesInSortedColumn.add("a");
        valuesInSortedColumn.add("zz");
        valuesInSortedColumn.add("b");
        valuesInSortedColumn.add("c");
        valuesInSortedColumn.add("zz");
        valuesInSortedColumn.add("");
        valuesInSortedColumn.add("");
        valuesInSortedColumn.sort(
                emptyValuesFirst().thenComparing(Comparator.reverseOrder())
        );
        System.out.println(valuesInSortedColumn);
```

**Output:** `[, , zz, zz, c, b, a]`